# custom buttons are not displaying in Microsoft Office Outlook Client 2010

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have added two custom button in my order entity.

Both are displaying in Web version of CRM 2013 but not displayed CRM Outlook 2010.

I have tried using Workbench 2013.

Can anyone have idea to display those buttons using Workbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figure this out but i am not sure what is the actual fix for this.

The things i have done :

**1.** Apply a display rule to one the group control, which contains OrGroup as following

[image]

**NOTE :** for some entity i am able to display buttons in outlook without

- MiscellaneousPrivilegeRule
- CrmOfflineAccessStateRule

**2.** Another rule is Enable rule as per following

[image]

**3.** Delete my Internet Explorer cache (used by the CRM Outlook Client)

**4.** Fix javascript errors, which might cause this issue using [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Custom Code Validation Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30151)

**5.** Also check for any UI errors in Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

To see buttons in Outlook they must have either an enabled and display rule applied that checks for either the Web or Outlook client and returns true accordingly for each.  So in your case because you want the button to appear in both you must apply a rule that checks for each and returns true.

The RibbonWorkbench developer blog provides [further information](http://www.develop1.net/public/post/Make-sure-ribbon-buttons-appear-in-Outlook.aspx).

Comment: I have applied the same rules (both display and enable rule) but buttons are not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

1) Check for UI errors in Outlook: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx

2) Make sure you have the CRM 2013 Outlook Client installed + the same/later rollup version as the CRM server.

3) Re-add the organization to the CRM Outlook Client
- Publish all customizations
- Remove the organization in Outlook
- Delete your Internet Explorer cache (used by the CRM Outlook Client).
- Re-add the organization to Outlook

4) If possible try with another computer that has a different Office version to test if the problem is related to the Outlook Client or to the ribbon customizations is CRM.